# android BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() image type?

Tags: android, opencv, yuv, rgba, bitmapfactory

does anybody know what pixel type does `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` returns?

basicly i'm using this snippet on the camera preview callback:

```
YuvImage img = new YuvImage(mLastFrame, ImageFormat.NV21, mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height, null);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
img.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height), 30, out);
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(out.toByteArray(), 0, out.size());
```

i get a good Bitmap which i can use with android. but if i want to use it with OpenCV, it doesn't work, and as OpenCV requires an ARGB_8888 type, i'm guessing, i get another type from the `decodeByteArray()` function.

thanks,
Vlad

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bitmap.getConfig()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getConfig%28%29) on your resulting `Bitmap` and see if it is `ALPHA_8, RGB_565` etc...

Comment: thanks! i don't know why i didn't think about that myself.. :P